# Property of convex functions.

Tags: analysis

I have seen the following argument:

> If $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, then there exist a Borel function $\lambda\colon\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded on compact subsets, and such that
>   \begin{equation}
> F(w) \ge F(z) + \langle \lambda(z), w-z\rangle
> \end{equation}
>   for every $z,w \in \mathbb{R}^n.$

Why is this true? Can you give one answer or a reference? if you know something similar, please tell me.
 Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can think of this as saying that *convex functions are differentiable*? Just a feeling.

Comment: Did you mean $F:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will correct.

Comment: @awllower Convex functions are not necessarily differentiable. The inequality in question doesn't say that the graph of $F$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ has a tangent hyperplane. Rather, it says that, through any point $(z,F(z))$, there is a hyperplane that lies entirely below the graph of $F$ ("below" in the weak sense of $\leq$, not $<$).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the reminder! I know that the statement is absolutely wrong, while, in some sense, it serves to tell us that the convex functions are very restrictive. In fact, I remember seeing some proof that convex functions are "almost" differentiable. But I forgot the definition of the italicized term, so I just gave a suggestion, as one possible direction. And no confusion is intended. Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: $\lambda$ is called a sub-gradient. For $n = 1$ it is Borel measurable simply because it is non-decreasing. In higher dimensions it may be a little more complicated.